# How can I ensure one particular PHPUnit TestCase is run before the others?

Tags: php, phpunit

Let's assume I have the following files, each of them containing a class that extends my `TestCase`:

```
- Tests
    - Feature
        ...
    -Integration
        ...
    - Unit
        - ModelTest.php
        - BillModelTest.php
        - ProductModelTest.php
        - CustomerModelTest.php
```

I'm indifferent as to the order the specific model tests run in, but I would like the `ModelTest` to run first (to be clear, `ModelTest.php` tests generic model behaviour and built-in methods, while the other tests run tests that are specific to that model).

None of these tests actually *depend* on each other, so it's not a big issue if they run in whatever they choose - but if a test is going to fail because the base Model's `getById()` method is failing, I'd rather catch that in the test *for that method*, than in an unrelated test that assumes `getById()` works as expected.

So far, I've thought of two possible solutions:

1. Put `ModelTest.php` in its own Test Suite. I don't like this solution because a) I don't want to make a bunch of granular test suites if I run into this issue frequently, and b) if I just want to run my `Unit Test` suite I would actually need to run *two* test suites instead, and frankly, `ModelTest.php` doesn't *belong* in a separate test suite, it's a unit test.
2. Change the file name so that it alphabetically runs first. This one is *more* acceptable to me but I still don't like it as it clutters the filenames and makes the application feel less clean overall.

Is there any other way to ensure that one particular TestCase will run before others?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter.

If you are generating code coverage reports when running PHPUnit, you will see that it tells you how many of your tests actually called that code.

So don't worry about it!

[image]